# How to refresh jQuery event bind after asp:button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need a way to refresh this jQuery code:

```
$(".alert_info").colorbox({
    inline: true, width: "50%",
    onOpen: function () {
    }
});
```

after clicking an asp button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

I tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".alert_info").colorbox({
       inline: true, width: "50%",
       onOpen: function () {
       }
   });
});
```

it didn't work...

I tried using:

```
$(".alert_info").on("click", function () {
        $(".alert_info").colorbox({
            inline: true, width: "50%",
            onOpen: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

it also didn't work...

this is the input with class .alert_info:

```
<a class="alert_info cboxElement" href="#alertWin10">View details</a>
```

Comment: did you check browser error console? Is there any error?

Comment: Have you included <script> tag to link `Colorbox` in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this finally solved it:

```
$(function () {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            $(".alert_info").colorbox({
                inline: true, width: "50%",
                onOpen: function () {
                    var json = $.parseJSON($(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").first().val());

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is a link that shows a solution [See "mitsbits" answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1608123.aspx?Color%20Box%20Jquery%20Not%20Working%20in%20Update%20Panel%20After%20the%20Initial%20Postback)

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind your event listeners when there is a postback or parital post back.  You should be able to target the `pageLoad` event in your js.  Another option is to place all the initilization code in the  (javascript) `pageLoad` function since the event should be triggered anytime there is a postback or partial postback (ajax/update pannels).

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    //rebind events here
}
```

This is just one of the reasons I dislike WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps and see if your problem is solved.

1. assign the below code to a string

   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".alert_info").colorbox({
      inline: true, width: "50%",
      onOpen: function () {
      }
   });
   });
2. Use Scriptmanager.RegisterStartupScript and pass the properties values along with the script string and invoke the same from the button click event from code behind.

This will invoke the code and refresh your script.